# How to use JDBI to insert multiple rows with a single INSERT?

Tags: java, jdbi

I'm trying to figure out how to do multi-row insert statements with JDBI.

Here is what I've got:

```java
@SqlBatch("INSERT INTO my_table(col1, col2) VALUES (:col1, :col2)")
@BatchSize(size=300)
public abstract int[] insertRows(@BindBean MyObj ... objs);
```

... which works fine, but results in as many INSERT statements as there are rows being inserted. I.e. if there are two rows being inserted, it results in something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(col1, col2) VALUES ('a', 'b');
INSERT INTO my_table(col1, col2) VALUES ('c', 'd');
```

... when what I want looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(col1, col2) VALUES ('a', b'), ('c', 'd');
```

I'd like it to take a variable number of objects as input. I don't think JDBI can do this, at least not easily... But can it?

Comment: Which version of Jdbi are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.55

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `@BindBeanList` annotation in v3 should accomplish you what you want:

```
@SqlUpdate("insert into my_table (col1, col2) values <values>")
int insertRows(@BindBeanList(propertyNames = {"col1", "col2"}) MyObj... objs);
```

The difference is I replaced `@SqlBatch` with `@SqlUpdate`, and `int[]` return type became just `int` since this is now a single statement.

Comment: BindBeanList doesn't seem to be working with insert statements (works fine with select statement). I had to use SqlBatch only in the end.

Comment: Wow.  Would have been swell if `@BindBeanList` was included in the docs.  :|

Comment: _"@SqlBatch was replaced with @SqlUpdate"_ -- not according to the API docs: http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/sqlobject/statement/SqlBatch.html